# iPhone : generating random paths for animations

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, sdk

I am able to my animation in a linear path. How do I get program them to move in a random path? I read developer's "move me" sample codes but it wasn't clear enough. Are there other tutorials out there for animations such as these?

```
//Loading the array with images
        NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"enemyball.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"playerball.png"]
                             , nil];

        //animation of images
        UIImageView *animatedView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 50.0, 50.0)];

        animatedView.animationImages = myImages;
        animatedView.animationDuration = 0.25; // seconds
        animatedView.animationRepeatCount = 0; //0 loops for ever/noted
        [animatedView startAnimating];
        [self addSubview:animatedView];


        //animation movement
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:4];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

        [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:INFINITY];
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(100, 0);
        animatedView.transform = transform;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Please paste the code here ... there are many ways in which animation can be done .. It won't be clear which method have you used

Comment: I have added the codes. I am using block animation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are asking about animation techniques or if you are just asking about random walks. If the later, the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) is a good start.